# Bash search with printing modifications

Tags: bash, grep

How to print content of all files of a directory if one of its file contain required data..... using bash?
I tried using 'grep' recursively but it only prints content of a single file! what to do ?
for example,
If I have two directories abc and xyz.abc has a file f1.txt("This is File1.") and f2.txt("This is File2.").xyz hav a file x.txt("fake f1")and y.txt("fake f2").
Now if I grep for File1, then output should be :
This is File1.
This is File2.

Comment: I would do: `bash -c 'cat $(grep -l "pattern" $(find . -type f ))'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -q "required data" "$1" && cat "$1"' -- {} \;
```

- `.` current directory
- `-type f` : only *files*
- `-exec` : execute
- executed: `bash` taking $1 argument from following `{}`, and using boolean logic to do some actions : `true condition && cat file`, short version for `if condition; then action; fi`
- `--` end of options security
- `{}` the current file place holder
- \; the find's end syntax

Comment: Can you please explain what each term of above command mean/do ?

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script will print the contents of all files of a directory if any file in that directory contains the required data:

```
find . -type d | while read dir; do find ${dir} -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read file; do if grep -q "search string" ${file}; then cat ${dir}/* 2>/dev/null; break; fi; done; done
```

Replace `search string` with the string that you want to search. You can either run this directly on the command-line or put it in a bash script and then run it.

**Explanation:**

1. Fetch all the directories using `find`.

   For each directory found above, `find` all the files in that directory only.

   For each file found above, if the file contains the required content, print the contents of all the files in that directory and exit that directory.

   If no file contains the required content, do nothing.

Comment: I don't think it's working..... :(

Comment: Are you not getting any result or are you getting incorrect result?

Comment: not getting any result

Comment: I assume you are running this script in the proper directory hierarchy where the expected file(s) are and you replaced `search string` with the string that you want to search. If you want to do case-insensitive search, add a `-i` flag to `grep`. Also, if you want to include symlinked files, add `-L` flag as the first option to both `find`s.